# Extract Confluence version from URL, HTML, or JSON

Tags: bash, curl, grep, confluence

I'm trying to extract the *version* from an URL like

```
https://my.atlassian.com/download/feeds/current/confluence.json
```

Here my bash script:

```
#!/bin/bash

# Get the actual version
url="https://de.atlassian.com/software/confluence/download"
actual_version="$(curl -s $url | grep -Po '(?<=version :)\d+' | head -1)"

echo $actual_version
```

Unfortunately it doesn't give me just the version number.

Any idea how to do this the correct way?

Note: question had multiple improvements / revisions based on comments.

Comment: Try changing `[^;]` to `[0-9.]`

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Tried, but no match

Comment: Can you add example of their source with mentionned `href="<%= downloadLink %>"` as readers may not have same source than you see (For example: I don't see `.exe` download links because I am a Linux user, the site propose me Linux download when I call https://de.atlassian.com/software/confluence/download)

Comment: After testing their download page, there may be javascript required to replace download link by real link with version. Maybe you would better try to extract their JSON instead ? Search for "JSON" in their source. I found this page : https://my.atlassian.com/download/feeds/current/confluence.json

Comment: You have changed the start URL. In new URL you provided `https://confluence.atlassian.com/doc/confluence-release-notes-327.html
`, is `327` the version you wan't to extract, right?

Comment: No, the version is within the source code in the <meta> tags: <meta name="product-version" content="6.11" /> - Where 6.11 is the actual version

Comment: I would suggest using a proper JSON parser like `jq`, except `confluence.json` isn't actually valid JSON. I'm not sure why the JSON is wrapped in `download(...)`, but minus that, you could simply use something like `curl ... | jq '.[].version'`. This would give you all the versions; you didn't specify which one you actually want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**TL;DR**

Here is the final command to extract the version from their JSON page:

```
curl -s "https://my.atlassian.com/download/feeds/current/confluence.json" | grep -Po '(?<="version":")[^"]*'  | head -1
6.11.0
```

**Details**

Have a look on this url returning JSON with product version : https://my.atlassian.com/download/feeds/current/confluence.json

Here is a copy of the JSON source at time of writing:

```
downloads([{"description":"6.11.0 - Linux Installer (64 bit)","zipUrl":"https://www.atlassian.com/software/confluence/downloads/binary/atlassian-confluence-6.11.0-x64.bin","tarUrl":null,"md5":"5ce76e5763b97b93db21ba447b5fb4f0","size":"564.1 MB","released":"12-Aug-2018","type":"Binary","platform":"Unix","version":"6.11.0","releaseNotes":"https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/DOC/Confluence+6.11+Release+Notes","upgradeNotes":"https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/DOC/Confluence+6.11+Upgrade+Notes"},{"description":"6.11.0 - Windows Installer (64 bit)","zipUrl":"https://www.atlassian.com/software/confluence/downloads/binary/atlassian-confluence-6.11.0-x64.exe","tarUrl":null,"md5":"71c6f1275cc4ed6089871e5a7fd1f09b","size":"564.4 MB","released":"12-Aug-2018","type":"Binary","platform":"Windows","version":"6.11.0","releaseNotes":"https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/DOC/Confluence+6.11+Release+Notes","upgradeNotes":"https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/DOC/Confluence+6.11+Upgrade+Notes"},{"description":"6.11.0 - Standalone (TAR.GZ Archive)","zipUrl":"https://www.atlassian.com/software/confluence/downloads/binary/atlassian-confluence-6.11.0.tar.gz","tarUrl":null,"md5":"4c245b2b1dcc18ec9aff483c708f937e","size":"510.4 MB","released":"12-Aug-2018","type":"Binary","platform":"Unix, Mac OS X","version":"6.11.0","releaseNotes":"https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/DOC/Confluence+6.11+Release+Notes","upgradeNotes":"https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/DOC/Confluence+6.11+Upgrade+Notes"},{"description":"6.11.0 - Standalone (ZIP Archive)","zipUrl":"https://www.atlassian.com/software/confluence/downloads/binary/atlassian-confluence-6.11.0.zip","tarUrl":null,"md5":"f6d08f93840b92a2fbf9ac0005f249fb","size":"512.4 MB","released":"12-Aug-2018","type":"Binary","platform":"Windows","version":"6.11.0","releaseNotes":"https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/DOC/Confluence+6.11+Release+Notes","upgradeNotes":"https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/DOC/Confluence+6.11+Upgrade+Notes"}])
```

There, you can find the version :

[image]

Comment: This was a quick search, you would better check if confluence do provide REST api or whatever way to extract their info

Comment: That's a very good approach. Lemme try to get the 'version:*'

Comment: Ok, correct string is: "curl -s https://my.atlassian.com/download/feeds/current/confluence.json | grep -Po '(?<="version":")[^"]*' | head -1" You can add this to your answer if you want to